# how to display 2 directory lists side by side in node.js express

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, pug, stylus

scenario:
 clients can upload to 2 directories

wanted result:
 client can see the listings of both directories side by side

am newbie to these.

1. a couple of jquery listbox widgets to display the directory listing
2. can new entries be automatically shown or limited to clients hitting a "refresh" button?

is this feasible/possible?

are there packages in npm that does part of the above already?

thanks for any/all opinions/ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you can do everything you want to by just a little bit of HTML/CSS.  In the simplest form just do something like this.

```
var fs = require('fs');

app.get('/foo', function(req, res){

    fs.readdir('dir1', function(error, result){

        res.write('<div class="bar">');
        res.write('<ul>');
        //write out all of the files as list
        res.write('</div>');
        fs.readdir('dir2', function(error, result){
            res.write('<div class="bar">');
            res.write('<ul>');
            //write out all of the files as lis
            res.write('</div>');
            res.end();
        });
    });
});
```

Then, on the client side, make a css rule

```
 .bar{
     float: left;
 }
```

That will pull them both to the left assuming that they are both in a relative wrapper div.  You can gussy it up with jquery/css as much as you want from there.  This will update the two of them every time that there's a request (i.e. on refresh).  If you want it happen in real-time then look into Socket.io or some other websocket tool.

Comment: No problem.  Also, remember that node.js is a server-side technology, so if your question is ever "how do I show x in a certain way", the answer is probably not "do something different in node", it's "do something different with your html/css/frontend js"

Comment: You could run those fs.readdir()'s in parallel using `async.parallel()` https://github.com/caolan/async